How to get the URL endpoint and the GET/POST method when an Exception occurs?
I use a suspend function to call the API as shown in the code below. How can I get the URL endpoint and the GET/POST method when an Exception occurs?
suspend fun <T : BaseResponse> safeCallApi(
    api: suspend () -> Response<T>
): Result<T> {
    return try {
        val response = api()
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            val body = response.body()
            if (body != null) {
                Result.success(body)
            } else {
                Result.failure(BodyNullException())
            }
        } else {
            Result.failure(ServerException())
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        // I want to obtain the information about the URL endpoint and the GET/POST method there.
        Result.failure(UnknownException(e))
    }
}


response.raw().request.url 

should give you the url
response.raw().request.method 

should give what type of method (get,post,put etc) was used for the call

I need to get information (url, method) when an api call throws an exception...

ok? I gave you the solution

catch (e: Exception) {
// I want to obtain the information about the URL endpoint and the GET/POST method there.
Result.failure(UnknownException(e))
}

You will not be able to there, if you get an exception the request didn't even go through and retrofit does not provide a way to get that information outside of a response. You may have better luck with just using OkHttp without retrofit
